# Improve function speed that uses remainder:

Tags: actionscript-3

Please have a look at this piece of code:

```
public static function getCharLocationById(id:int):Point {
    var lx:int = id % 16;
    var ly:int = id / 16;
    return new Point(lx, ly);
}
```

It works perfectly but is very slow. Does anyone know of a way to make it much faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define "*very slow*"? Unless you're calling this thousands of times a second, I don't see why it should be slow. Are you sure it's coming from here and not because you're adding a lot of items to the stage? What do you use this for? Can you try to time it? The only thing I can think of is the creation of the `Point` object, but "very slow" makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks h2ooo. I am calling it at least many dozens of times per second. Adobe Scout shows it as a major overhead.

Comment: The first thing I would try to do was avoid the creation of the `Point` class. That said, function calls *do* create overhead.

Comment: Those are excellent suggestions. Let me run some tests while reusing the same point object and taking out the function. Thanks!

Comment: This almost looks like a port from the .NET way of doing things.  .NET uses `Point` objects a good bit idiomatically, but this isn't the case with AS3 (for good reason).  I'm not sure if this a port or not, but h2ooooooo is certainly correct.  Function calls add overhead, but object instantiation is noticeably worse.  That's a big reason you have object pools - to avoid creating objects, often at the expense of making extra method calls.  Also you might be setting properties, not actually variables, which is loosely the same as calling a function.

Comment: So try this:  1) Inline the function.  2) Don't use `Point` objects; just set `x` and `y` of whatever it is directly.  Modify the "other class" if necessary and possible.  3) If `Point` objects are necessary, just reuse the same one(s) as much as possible.  4) Try to avoid setting `x` or `y` to the same values for the same objects over and over, if possible; try to minimize the number of `for` loop iterations in the calling code, if applicable, for instance. 5) See ***if*** it might be faster to change this from checking stuff on a regular basis to simply handling callbacks.

Comment: 6) Try to avoid going through local variables like `lx` and `ly`, if possible.  This last point applies fairly specifically to this situation though.  If in other, unrelated code, you need to access the value of a member variable/property of something over and over again in the same function definition, it's often more efficient to temporarily make a local variable, work with it, and if applicable (like with value types), finally copy its value back to the member variable/property once you're done.

Comment: Thanks Panzer! I greatly appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the objects beforehand for all possibilities, all you have to do is look them up in an array (with the id as index).

```
private static const _locationLookUpTable:Array = []; //or Vector, if you like

// fill the array somewhere, maybe like this
for (var i:uint = 0; i <= maximumId; ++i) _locationLookUpTable.push(i % 16, i / 16);

public static function getCharLocationById(id:int):Point {
    return _locationLookUpTable[id];
}
```

If the number of ids is not limited or very large you can employ an object pool.
This requires a little more code as you should return the objects to the pool if they are not used any more.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the variable creations, only takes time to create, assign and then again read them to submit them to the `Point` constructor.

```
public static function getCharLocationById(id:int):Point 
{
    return new Point(id % 16,  id / 16);
}
```

Also, considering that your input is an integer, you can use bitshifts for the division by 16 like this:

```
id = id >> 1; // div. by 2 = id/2
id = id >> 1; // div. by 2 = id/2/2 = id/4
id = id >> 1; // div. by 2 = id/2/2/2 = id/8
id = id >> 1; // div. by 2 = id/2/2/2/2 = id/16
```

Shortening that we get

```
id = id >> 4; // (1+1+1+1 = 4)
```

Keep in mind that the result will also be an integer, so `11 >> 1` will return `5` and **not** `5.5`.